# Como simulo que existe una pagina en el Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

El objetivo final que quiero es llegue un request (ej: Pepe.aspx) y se ejecute directamente un metodo de C#. Ya lo logre pero el HttpContext tiene la session en null (ya se porque esta en null)

**En el global.asax puse:**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (BaseApp.VirtualPageManager.ExecutePage())
     {
        CompleteRequest();
     }
}
```

Esa funcion magicamente busca y ejecuta el metodo de esta clase:

```
public class TestPage: IVirtualPage
{
    public static void Pepe()
    {
        //Do something..
        Request;
        Response;
        HttpContext.Current.Session;
    }
}
```

Eso funciona ya, pero session obviamente esta siempre null porque estoy llamando la funcion desde el BeginRequest del global.

**Ahora si lo saco del begin request y pongo:**

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (BaseApp.VirtualPageManager.ExecutePage(Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath), Request, Response))
  {
     CompleteRequest();
  }
}
```

Pero si hago esto nunca se llega a ejecutar Application_AcquireRequestState porque no existe Pepe.aspx. Por eso mi idea era averiguar como puedo decirle de alguna forma si existe, procesala dame la session yo despues me encargo de devolverte un request.

Alguna idea de como tener la session o concejos sobre como crear una pagina virtual?